# Is it possible to force kableExtra to use UTF-8?

Tags: r, utf-8, latex, kableextra

Does anyone know If you can force kableExtra to save a .tex file as UTF-8 instead of ANSI? Since I have the Swedish letter å, ä, ö in my table, converting my tex-file to pdf won't work unless it is in utf-8 format. If I open up my tex-file and resave it as UTF-8, it works but is not really a solution for me.

I'm not sure it's kableExtra that is the problem. It might also be something with this Rstuido installation that is the problem (recently installed R / Rstudio on a new computer).

This is the command I use to save my table:

```
kableExtra::save_kable(table, file = "C:/PATH/table.tex")
```

Heres my sessionInfo:

```
R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Swedish_Sweden.1252  LC_CTYPE=Swedish_Sweden.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Swedish_Sweden.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=Swedish_Sweden.1252
```

Let me know if you need any more info!

**EDIT:**
Here's a small reprex:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyverse)

test <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + wt, mtcars) %>% tidy() %>%
  kbl(format = "latex") %>% 
  footnote(number = c("Testa å ä ö"))

save_kable(test, file = "plain.tex")
```

So the plain.tex is ansi, but I want UTF-8.

Comment: Did you already try with the `ansinew` option of the `inputenc` package? If this matches the encoding of your file, latex should be able to print your letters.

Comment: Do you make a table in your console or in Rmd-file??

Comment: @manro: table is made with the modelsummary and kableextra package. I save I as an object in are and then use kableExtra::save_kable(table, file = "C:/PATH/table.tex") to save it to my hardrive. The problem is that its saved as ansi. If I open it with notepad and save it as UTF-8 - the conversion to pdf will work.

Comment: Not currently on Windows but have you tried setting `Encoding(test) <- 'UTF-8'` before saving it? Besides this it seems like you don’t actually need `save_kable`: in your case it just calls `writeLines` internally; you could do the same.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yup! Does noting I'm afraid..

Comment: Hm. Then the last thing you can try is using `writeLines` with an explicit connection rather than a file: `writeLines(test, file('test.tex', encoding = 'UTF-8'), TRUE)`. If that also fails, try playing around with `iconv` … but it seems as if the text isn’t actually encoded correctly inside R. Hopefully all this nonsense will stop in the near future when R finally ships with proper Unicode support for Windows.

Comment: I have an idea, when I return to home - I try to produce.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I got it to work by removing TRUE from your code: writeLines(one, file('test.tex', encoding = 'UTF-8')). Thanks for this.

Comment: @manro Thanks. It will be interesting if you can figure it out.  Note that we have one semi-solution above!

Comment: @TomasR Sorry, my method didn't work(